# Apache error with environment variables (Ubuntu)

Tags: apache, environment-variables, ubuntu-12.04

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04, I have installed separately Apache, Php and Mysql. I've never had a problem, but after an Ubuntu update I always get a "404 Not Found" error when I try to access a php file on my web server.

When I write "apache2 -S" on my console I get this:

```
[Sat Feb 22 16:15:16.983766 2014] [core:warn] [pid 4475] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Sat Feb 22 16:15:16.983871 2014] [core:warn] [pid 4475] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Sat Feb 22 16:15:16.983914 2014] [core:warn] [pid 4475] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Sat Feb 22 16:15:16.983936 2014] [core:warn] [pid 4475] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Sat Feb 22 16:15:16.983966 2014] [core:warn] [pid 4475] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Sat Feb 22 16:15:16.987930 2014] [core:warn] [pid 4475:tid 139974428579648] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
[Sat Feb 22 16:15:16.988259 2014] [core:warn] [pid 4475:tid 139974428579648] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Sat Feb 22 16:15:16.988433 2014] [core:warn] [pid 4475:tid 139974428579648] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Sat Feb 22 16:15:16.988456 2014] [core:warn] [pid 4475:tid 139974428579648] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 75 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 5):

from reading [this bug page](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=719280), I surmised that all of these are environment variables that need to be exported before you can run apache2. Apparently these are loaded automatically from /etc/apache2/envvars when you run it as a service like "service apache2 start". Another option is to start it up with apache2ctl.

Answer (score 0):

Thats what I get also, when I enter apache2 -S, but everything is working.
If you look at apache man page - it is just related to some config parsed data. Do you have any errors from your PHP code ? Take a look at apache log files - they are stored under **var/log/apache2** directory.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. My log says: AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'... I don't really know what the problem is, I'm struggling with this since 2 weeks ago. No php errors. Just the 404 error. Before this Ubuntu update everything was working fine.

Comment: Well I would recommend you to remove all stack and them fresh install. Here is a good guide http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-13.04-lamp

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue running Bugzilla locally via Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu Server 14.04. Running the command `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 graceful` got the page to load, where previously Chrome was telling me that no data had been received. I hope someone more knowledgeable than I can explain why this was effective, but `service apache2 start` and `apache2ctl` were not.